# How to pause a submit event until an AJAX event finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form and a submit. If something is filled, before submit I want to make sure its a good value (with ajax) and if so, THEN I can only let it continue. So,

```
$('#contact').submit(function() {
  // ajax
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(this).attr('ajaxgetaccommodationsbyemail'),
    success: function(answer) {
        here a popup window opens, which waits  until I press YES or NO
    },
    async: false
  });

   this is when return TRUE or FALSE
   there should be something like
   do while (popupWindowClosed)
   so $.when is not an option

});
```

Comment: Set a global variable when the AJAX returns successfully. Cancel the `submit` event if the global variable isn't set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prevent the submit with jQuery, and then actually call the native submit to send the form

```
$('#contact').on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var form = this;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('ajaxgetaccommodationsbyemail'),
        success: function(answer) {
             popup(function(yesorno) {

                 if (yesorno) {
                     form.submit();
                 }

             });
        }
    });
});
```

And the `async:false` removed because you should ***never*** do syncronous ajax.

Comment: but the "if ( confirm('Are you sure') ) {" is not like that. Its another "asynchronous" thing

Comment: Doesn't matter, the same principle applies, you add the popup inside the `success` function, and if it's a custom popup, it has a callback, where you can call `submit()`, I'll edit the answer back to how it was initially

Comment: but. On submit, the default behaviour is disabled. When I call form.submit() it will disable the default behaviour again....

Comment: Nope, not if you call the *native* submit

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#contact').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  // ajax
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(this).attr('ajaxgetaccommodationsbyemail'),
    success: function(answer) {
        $.dialog(function(){ // this line is "pseudocode", put the code of your dialog here.
          // when clicked YES
          form.submit();
        }, function(){
          // when clicked NO
        });
    }
  });
});
```

If you actually want a customizable dialog, you can use: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score 1):

jQuery ajax has error and success callbacks. You can do something like following:

```
$('#contact').submit(function() {
  // ajax
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(this).attr('ajaxgetaccommodationsbyemail'),
    error: function (request, error) {
        // there was error. handle it how you want
    },
    success: function () {
        // open your pop up window 
        // and do other stuff
    }
  });

});
```